# Find occurance of string and insert new string efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to be able to parse a string containing XML and 'repair' it by modifying a tag.  For instance, I need to replace all occurrences of `fontSize="16"` with `fontSize="16px".`

What's an efficient (but readable) way of doing this in c# and .NET?  I had started down the route of a using `IndexOf` within a while loop but thought there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: [`.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Bobson, but I wont know the exact search string every time.  i.e., the fontSize=" is constant, but the value isn't.

Comment: Have you tried a Regex (assuming this isn't XML or HTML data, where other, safer, more efficient methods may exist)

Comment: Assuming it starts off as valid well formed xml then I'd probably look at using an XML parser for maximum reliability.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - This actually seems like a good example of when you *would* want to use a Regex on XML, simply because it doesn't matter that it's XML.

Comment: I would either use regex on the whole file, or parse as XML and grab just the attributes I want and use regex from there.

Comment: To answer the question we need to know how well formatted the xml is and if case sensitive. BTW, i beleive while loop with indexof is the most efficient way

Comment: why don't you just a real xml api?

Comment: In this scenario, parsing it as XML would be horribly *inefficient*, because you would then have to search every node in the entire structure for `fontSize` attributes, check whether the attribute's value contains the desired `px`, change it if not, then write the whole thing back out.  Much better to just treat it as a giant string.

Comment: @Bobson - not parsing as XML assumes that "fontsize=xx" should always be replaced in any context. That may well be the case, and if so, then no parsing required. However, applying a replace to the whole file *could* have unintended consequences. If the stated example is the only case, then I would agree parsing is overkill. But if extended to other attributes, that could be a different story.

Comment: @JonB - It's true.  It's always possible that the value of a node contains text which happens to match, or that it should only be applied to certain nodes.  And as the rules get more complex, parsing it as XML becomes a better idea.  But *as given*, those aren't constraints that need to be worried about.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys.  As a newbie, this is part of the problem for me, there are usually many ways of achieving the same thing.  Have fun, Dave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Regex.Replace()`:

```
Regex.Replace(inputText, @"fontSize=""(\d+)""", @"fontSize=""$1px""")
```

The second argument finds all examples of `fontsize="..."` where `...` represents digits only.  Since there's a following `"`, it won't match anything that's already in the form `16px`.  The third argument tells it what to replace the match with - in this case, the same string with an extra `px` added after the number (`$1`).

Comment: Thanks Bobson for both the answer and the clear explanation.  Trying it now.  Dave

Answer (score 3):

If your playing with XML, I'd use the right tool for the job: `XDocument`. Here is an example:

```
var input = @"
<root>
  <someTag fontSize=""16"" />
  <someTag otherAttribute=""12"" />
</root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var allAttributes = doc.Descendants().Attributes();

var fontSizeAttributes = allAttributes.Where(x => x.Name == "fontSize");

foreach (var f in fontSizeAttributes)
    f.Value = Regex.Replace(f.Value, "^([0-9].)$", "$1px");
```

Results in `doc` containing:

```
<root>
  <someTag fontSize="16px" />
  <someTag otherAttribute="12" />
</root>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace an existing `fontSize="16px"` with `fontSize="16pxpx"`?  You need the surrounding quotes in the Regex expression.  Other than that, this is how I'd do it if it had to be treated as XML.